# During Segmentation fault can destructor called

Tags: c++

Hi friend i have one query during program execution if segmentation fault occurs ,can the destructor of automatic created object called.
i am writing one code and intentionally creating segmentaion fault to check destructor willbe called or not it is not calling .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class hello
{
    public:
    int b;
};

class test
{
    public :
        hello *ptr;
        int a;
        void function()
            {
                ptr = new hello;

            }

        test()
        {
            cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
        }

        ~test()
        {
            cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
            delete ptr;
        }
};

    int main()
    {
        test obj;
        obj.function();
        obj.a = 500;

        test *ptr ;
        ptr-> a = 900;       //To create segmentation fault

    }
```

output:
constructor called

destructor is not being called.
so i am not able to delete any object created using "new" inside destructor

Comment: When your program crashes, the OS reclaims that memory anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
test *ptr ;
ptr-> a = 900;
```

is undefined behavior because `ptr` is a dangling pointer, so **anything can happen**. The destructor may or may not be called, anything is possible.

To make it point to a valid object, you can assign it to the adress of obj:

```
test* ptr = &obj;
```

To create a new dynamically-allocated object, you can use `new`:

```
test* ptr = new test;
```

but if you do this, you'll have to take care of memory management yourself:

```
delete ptr;
```

Comment: You missed the logic: *intentionally creating segmentaion fault to check destructor willbe called or not*. I don't blame you for it.

Comment: @chris but this falls under UB. The destructor could get called.

Comment: True as it is, the idea behind it is so that they can properly free their dynamically allocated memory, which doesn't actually matter in the whole scheme of things. Of course you could argue that the UB can affect the OS cleaning up, and I guess it does come into play if you don't crash, though nothing past that point is guaranteed.

Comment: It's undefined by the standard, but I think the combination of compiler and OS will have a predictable behavior as long as you're guaranteed the pointer is pointing to unallocated memory.

Comment: @MarkRansom you can't really make that guarantee. In fact, in release the pointer will most certainly not be initialized to NULL. And if the program allocates a lot of memory, or there is little memory available, the chances that it will point to memory you actually own and not trigger a system signal are fairly high.

Answer (score 1):

No, the destructor will not be called because a segmentation fault is the result of the operating system sending an interrupt to the program for trying to access memory which is protected.  The interrupt will halt the execution of the program and it will not be able to continue any further.

Comment: "No, the destructor will not be called" how do you know? You can't provide any guarantees when it comes to undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I believe the rest of my answer explains why it should not be called.

Comment: Not really. A conforming implementation could just as well not crash.

Comment: so where should i free the memory which is created by "new" in case of segmentation fault or crash in program.

Comment: As chris pointed out in a comment on your question, the OS will reclaim the memory that your program was using.

Comment: @user1835342 Segmentation faults are unpredictable unless you write flawless code, so it can't always be your responsibility to free the memory in the event of the crash.  Note that it is possible to [capture and handle a segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).